# Find last translate

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following xml:

```
<item>value 1,value 2,value3,</item>
```

I would now like to achieve the following via an output via xslt:

```
<item>value 1,value 2,value3</item>
```

So remove the last comma. Can you help me?

Comment: Will there always be a trailing comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this template:

```
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring(.,string-length(.))=','">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,string-length(.)-1)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>      
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

It will only remove the last char when it is a comma.